# Two people are playing a game with an unfair coin: what’s the probability of winning

Tags: probability

> Bob and I are playing a game with an unfair coin that is rigged to come up heads with probability $\frac35$ and tails with probability $\frac25$. Bob goes first, we take turns, and the first player to flip a tail wins. What is Bob's probability of winning?

Is the answer just $\frac25$? But how do you take into consideration the infinite cases possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p = \frac 25$ be the probability of the game ending on the next flip.
Let $x$ be the probability that Bob wins. I say that
$$x = p + (1-p)(1-p)x.$$
I got this equation by considering the possibilities for the game:

- On turn 1, Bob wins with probability $p$
- We advance to turn 2 with probability $1-p$

  - We advance from turn 2 to turn 3 with probability $1-p$, otherwise the game ends.

    - From turn 3, the game looks exactly the same as if we were in turn 1 and the coin can't remember how it landed before so the probability of Bob winning from now on is $x$.

You can solve the above equation for $x$, substituting $p=\frac25$ to get the probability that Bob wins.

---

The general trick for problems like this is that instead of trying to add up an infinite number of probabilities, you should try to spot a relation between earlier and later turns of the game. Then you can usually construct a recurrence relation (not always as simple as the one above) and then solve that. Solving a recurrence relation is almost always easier than evaluating an infinite sum.

Comment: I like looking for renewals!  (Although, in this particular case, the infinite sums are fairly trivial to evaluate.)

Answer (score 1):

Another route to the same answer: Enumerate all the possible sequences for Bob to win, and for you to win.

Bob wins on T, HHT, HHHHT, HHHHHHT, etc.  These have probability $2/5, (3/5)^2(2/5), (3/5)^4(2/5), (3/5)^6(2/5), \ldots$

You win on HT, HHHT, HHHHHT, HHHHHHHT, etc.  These have probability $(3/5)(2/5), (3/5)^3(2/5), (3/5)^5(2/5), (3/5)^7(2/5), \ldots$

These cases are disjoint and exhaustive, so you can determine the chances of Bob winning by adding up the probabilities for each case; the same goes for your chances of winning.  If you use the formula for the sum of a geometric series:

$$
a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots = \frac{a}{1-r}
$$

with $r = (3/5)^2$, you should obtain your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we can do it by taking an infinite sum.

We write a formula for the probability that Bob wins on his $n$-th turn and then add all of those probabilities together. To win on the $n$-th turn, Bob must get tails (probability $\frac{2}{5}$), and all the previous flips must have been heads (so $2(n-1)$ flips of heads in a row which has probability $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{2(n-1)}$). Hence the chance of Bob winning on the $n$-th turn is $\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{2(n-1)}$. Summing up the probability, we get

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{2(n-1)}=\frac{2}{5}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{2n}=\frac{2}{5}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{9}{25}\right)^{n}=\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{9}{25}}\right)=\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{25}{16}\right)=\frac{5}{8}$$

Hence the answer is not $\frac{2}{5}$, but rather $\frac{5}{8}$.